# How to Redirect to a Different Domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to setup a directive in my .htaccess file to redirect as follows:

from http://mydomain.com/internal/

to http://myotherdomain.com/internal/

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

**MY CODE -- PRODUCES 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR**

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/internal[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/internal/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: For one thing, comments in .htaccess don't start with `//`

Comment: Good catch @Wooble -- actually I do know that they start with pound sign (#). I got the code from an online generator and never paid attention to that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few issues with your file: Comments start with `#` not `//`, you can't match the URI with HTTP_HOST (you were trying to match /internal), and there needs to be a space between the rule or cond and the flags (NC). This should work though:

```
#Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^internal(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/internal$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: for what it is worth @Ansari, the .htaccess file actually exists in the /internal/ directory itself as this is the only directory on the source domain that I want to redirect. The results just give me a directory listing of mydomain.com/internal

Comment: Glad to hear it - I was going to suggest that in addition to `RewriteBase /internal/`.

Comment: Question @Ansari (and others). I don't want any extra/superfluous stuff tacked on the the end of the natural URL nor do I want any query strings happening. So could I just revise the last directive to be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/internal/ [R=301,NC]` ? Would that still work?

Comment: Yes that would still work. To prevent the query string from being added on, add a question mark to the end like this: `http://myotherdomain.com/internal/? [R=301,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^internal(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/internal$1 [L,NC]
```

The `(.*)` will copy anything so you can use it in `$1`. If the redirect should be permanent, just add `R=301` after `L,NC`

**Edit**
Your mistakes in the given piece of codes are:

1. comments use "#"
2. The host is `^mydomain.com$`
3. You have to add a space between the host and `[NC]`
4. Write `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1` OR `RewriteRule ^internal/(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/internal/$1`, but your Rule will redirect to `internal/internal`

Comment: This won't work - you have to RewriteCond the HTTP_HOST before you can rewrite the domain.

Comment: This simply renders a directory listing of http://mydomain.com/internal/ @ChristopherBrix

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherBrix. I was far enough down the road with Ansari's suggestion that I ended up going with that one, but I up voted your answer as well.

Comment: @Dr.DOT You're right - I might have posted first but Ansari's solution was better (at first I had some mistakes in my solution)